# How to implement a bare-metal kernel scheduler?

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I would like to implement a very simple kernel on my microcontroller, and if possible, fully written in C. This kernel can basically do two sort of things:

- Execute preemptive threads (that are interrupted after a certain period of time)
- Execute non-preemptive threads (that cannot be interrupted by the kernel)

The latter requirement is very easy to implement because it can run using the kernel stack (which is not correctly shown on the figure below).

The former requirement is however very tricky to implement. Before branching to thread 1, the kernel starts a timer. It then switch the context (full processor context switch) to execute thread one. When the kernel interrupt isr occurs, the thread context is saved on the thread stack then the kernel context is restored from the kernel stack. At the end of the ISR, **it branches back to the kernel, not to thread 1**.

This bold sentence is precisely the topic of my question. A normal ISR usually ends with a RTI (return from interrupt) instruction that differ from the RTS (return from subroutine) because the processor context is restored from the default stack. In my case, no RTI occurs because I don't want to go back where I was (e.g. thread 1). I must manually modify the program counter to branch to the kernel while taking care of the hardware stacks that might be modified by the processor during the interrupt.

How can a kernel scheduler be implemented that avoid this tricky stack commutation using a timer ISR?

[image]

Comment: Interrupts should be as quick as possible. If not other interrupts might be blocked. As for your problem, why not use an `RTI` when the second (non-interruptible) thread has finished? I'm not saying your design is a good one (because of the long-running interrupt) but it is solvable.

Comment: Also, the usual way to solve process-switching is to simply change the stack pointer. Each thread has its own stack pointer (for kernel threads it's the kernel stack pointer). When a thread is preempted the stack pointer is stored in the threads control structure. To switch thread you get the stack pointer from another threads control structure and use it, then `RTI` as usual and the CPU will do the correct thing and start running the new thread. This is a long solved problem, and can in a simple way handle non-preemtable threads (check a flag in your ISR if the switch should happen or not).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree with your first remark, but most people tend to believe interrupts MUST be as short as possible, but they don't know that an interrupt has a considerable overhead due to the context switch. It means an interrupt with one instruction will still cost much more than one single instruction. So yes, an interrupt should be short, but relatively to its overhead.